# rsync simulate --ignore-missing-args on old server version

Tags: rsync

I have a a script that uses rsync arguments `--files-from` with an exact file list (no filter rules, no wildcards etc.) and `--ignore-missing-args`  (to ignore files that will be created in future by the server) to transfer files periodically.

The script should terminate on any major error (e.g. connection lost); On the server there is an older rsync (`3.0.4`; locally I have version `3.1.0`) version which does not support `--ignore-missing-args`:

```
rsync: on remote machine: --ignore-missing-args: unknown option
```

Without the `--ignore-missing-args` option any missing files (and in future to be created files) will result in an rsync error with return code not equal to `0`.

Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just update `rsync` on the other machine? That would be easiest workaround.

Comment: Its a hpc-cluster, I have no root access. And updating might take a long time.

Comment: There are some possible work-arounds here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86879, so maybe have a look. You might not get the same exact behavior though...

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

Use `--include-from` and add a `+` before every file listed in the file list, plus, add a `- *` to exclude any other files, e.g.

```
$ cat files.txt
+ foo.bar
+ bar.foo
- *
```

Final `rsync` command:

```
rsync --include-from=files.txt [path] [host]:[path]
```